# Design of a Drop Down list in Android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

Which Android design component should I use to create a drop down list for creating A "Frequently Asked Question" section in the Android app? The design would be similar to the attached image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WXFi.png)

Comment: Use ExpandedListView

Comment: ExpandableListView